# Capture live stream from camera byte by byte using Open CV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using a simulator (Its a collection of codes) that reads data from a source and converts them to signals (for example optical signal, etc.). I am trying to do implement the following in VS2019:

1. Capturing video from the camera byte by byte (I am not sure if it is possible)
2. Converting the video bytes into signal and saving them into the buffer (to this end the "bufferPut" function is used)
3. Encrypting this signal that contains video bytes
4. Sending encrypted data to another computer
5. Decrypting data in the second computer and playing the video

I was able to capture from camera frame by frame (but I need byte by byte) using this link: 
[Read and write video in Open CV](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

1. Could you please help me with how to capture byte by byte and not frame by frame?
2. If I need to use another library for this purpose, please let me know.

Here you can see my coding:

```
bool LoadFromCamera::runBlock(void) {

int space = outputSignals[0]->space();

if (!space) return false;


// # Create a VideoCapture object and use camera to capture the video ##############################
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);


// # Check if camera opened successfully ###########################################################
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    std::cerr << "Error opening video stream" << std::endl;
    return -1;

    //system("pause");
    //system("exit");

}

// # Default resolution of the frame ###############################################################
int frame_width = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int frame_height = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);


// # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object.The output is stored in 'outcpp.avi' file. #####
cv::VideoWriter video("outcpp.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, cv::Size(frame_width, frame_height));
while (1)
{
    cv::Mat frame;

    cap >> frame; // Capture frame-by-frame

    if (frame.empty()) // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        break;



    outputSignals[0]->bufferPut((std::byte*)frame.data, frame.rows * frame.cols * frame.channels()); // Converts the frame into signal and save it into buffer



    video.write(frame); // Writes the frame into the file 'outcpp.avi'

    imshow("Frame", frame); // Displays the resulting frame 

    char c = (char)cv::waitKey(1); // Press  ESC on keyboard to  exit
    if (c == 27)


        break;
}


// # Release the video capture and write object #################################################
cap.release();
video.release();

// # Closes all the windows #####################################################################
cv::destroyAllWindows();

return 0;
```

}

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Bytes... what bytes are you talking about? There's the bytes that are transferred between the image sensor and the camera controller/image processor, the bytes that are transferred over the camera connection (USB, Ethernet, ...), the bytes that are transferred between the USB or Network stack and the device driver, the bytes that are transferred between the media API and the application,...

I don't think you care about bytes in some special sense. You get an image, you want to encrypt it and send it onwards. All images are bytes underneath. There's literally nothing special to do. Use the [`cv::Mat.ptr`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a13acd320291229615ef15f96ff1ff738) to get a pointer to each row of the image, then encrypt it, and on the receiving end you need to set up a "blank" destination `cv::Mat` with same format and size (number of rows and columns), and then decrypt each incoming matrix row and write it into that matrix's row - obtained using the same `cv::Mat.ptr()` method.

If there's anything missing, you'll have to edit your question to make it clear what you really want to do.

Comment: Yes I don't care about bytes in some special sense. I will follow what you suggest. Thank you.